# mercurial hg - pushing to a cloned repository via APACHE errors with "repository is unrelated"

Tags: apache, mercurial, version-control, tortoisehg

Two scenarios, one work one doesn't when they both should:

- Scenario #1: (DOES NOT work via apache)

  - 2 repos on Server SERVER: Repo "A", Repo "B" cloned from repo A via http://SERVER/HG/A

    On client:
     
                    Repo A cloned from http://SERVER/HG/A
                    Repo B cloned from http://SERVER/HG/B

  Added a file to repo A from client and commited & pushed it up to http://SERVER/HG/A ...**WORKS**
  Added a file to repo B from client and commited & pushed it up to http://SERVER/HG/B ...**ERROR with abort: repository is unrelated**, it only works if I -f (force) the push

- Scenario #2: (works via file system)

  - On Server SERVER: Repo "A", Repo "B" cloned from E:/HG/A

    On client: 

    Repo A cloned from E:/HG/A

                    Repo B cloned from E:/HG/B

  Added a file to repo A from client and commited & pushed it up to E:/HG/A ...**WORKS** 
  Added a file to repo B from client and commited & pushed it up to E:/HG/B ...**WORKS**

**Conclusion:**...Something in the apache configuration or in the integration between apache & mercurial is making the repo "unrelated"....
Any ideas??? Why do I need to force in the first scenario but do not have to in the second?? 
...and i tried both scenarios via tortoisehg as well as command line.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know quite what's going wrong in your case, but I call tell that when mercurial says 'unrelated' it means: the two repositories do not have a root or roots.

Normally a mercurial repository has a single root, revision 0, and any repository with that same root can push to it.  A repository can have multiple roots, usually the result of someone doing a `push -f`.

So what you're doing in Scenario one, should exactly work.  If it's not then either your apache configuration is pointing `http://SERVER/HG/B` somewhere other than you think it should be (perhaps a bad `RewriteRule` or `RedirectMatch` or `ScriptAlias`, or your Repo B didn't clone from Repo A like you thought it did, or Repo A or B changed fundamentally after B was initially cloned.

There are some tools that will alter the hashcode of your root (revision 0) node if used to modify that node: mq, histedit, strip, rebase, etc.  And it's because changing the hash completely alters the repo that those tools are disabled by default and for use on local, un-pushed changes only.

To start debugging this, go onto the SERVER and see what happens if you do do incoming or outgoing between repos A and B at the file system level.  If those complain then you know it's not apache, and if they do, then it's something your Apache setup.